# Is there a "Default Order By Column" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

When I execute a query like `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table`, it gets sorted by the primary key ascending.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to specify a different column, like `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC` if there is no Order By clause?

I doubt it (since it would be very unintuitive, but just wondering anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Any ordering you see is an artifact of the query optimizer's strategy. Relational theory forbids that there is any implicit ordering of any set of data.

You can't even count on the same ordering next time for the same query because the optimizer strategy depends on the context and the data which might change.

Comment: Interesting, relational theory indeed specifies that `a set is an unordered collection of unique, non-duplicated items`.

Answer (score 12):

Even the behavior you are seeing (ordered by pk) is not guaranteed by the standard. You should always specify the order you want things to be retrieved.

Comment: But only if it matters which might not be true.

Comment: @le dorfier - that is correct, if you don't care about the order then there is no reason to use an ORDER BY clause.