# Change the order by when selecting "edit top 'N' rows"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to know if it is possible to change the ordering of the results when you right click a table in SSMS and select "edit top 'n' rows".

I have noticed it defaults the 'order by' to the first column.

Unfortunately I am manually updating records and it would save many hours if i could re order it to a column which maps directly to my Excel spreadsheet.

NOTE: I know how to change the number of rows I can edit (hence the reason i have used 'n' instead of the default: 200).

I just want to know if it is possible, perhaps from someone who knows the internals of it. I was hoping there is some script it executes and I could edit that script ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've not seen the possibility to change that part of the command. I'd think it properly would be much better for you to just make a script yourself that you can run.

Comment: Watch this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628636/is-there-a-default-order-by-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can right click on your result and select `pane\SQL` and then change your order and top amount of your query.

Comment: You champion :) thank you , will accept as soon as i am allowed

Comment: But that's not changing the default ordering of results for anything but that single query?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen. You can use sub query in your ordering and can have any ordering.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen true , let me rephrase my question, I only need it for this query , and any future ones i decide need re-ordering. Thank you Allan, i have changed the question and up'd you comment thanks

Comment: @mehdilotfi I know - but the question was asking to change the default ordering for the SSMS command; not ordering of the query which is why I'm "confused"

Answer (score 1):

after selecting edit row, right click and select pane > criteria. theres sorting in each column.

Comment: This question is asked more than 8 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer